# Unable to set constraint for UIView

Tags: ios, uiview, constraints, settings

I am new to app making and trying to make a single view app. There is a button at the bottom of the screen on click of which I want to expand a `UIView` which will have other buttons as well to navigate further.

iPhone 11 Pro Max simulator image:

[image: iPhone 11 Pro Max simulator image]

However, while checking this layout for a smaller device, the circle is getting clipped as shown below from the sides:

iPhone 8 simulator image:

[image: iPhone 8 simulator image]

The dimensions for the `UIView` is width = 414 and height = 400 (to make it look right on iPhone 11 Pro Max).

Autoresizing and setting constraint doesn't really help.

Appreciate any and every kind of input.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you making the semicircle? Can you share your code?

Comment: @Manoj i am usin a UIView and changing the corener radius to make it a circle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Initially, set height constraint to 0 of UIView you want to expand.
2. Once you click the bottom button, change UIView height constraint to 
   whatever you want.

To set height constraint value-

1. Create outlet of height constraint of UIView which you want to expand.
2. set yourViewHeightConstraint.constant = 0 or 
   yourViewHeightConstraint.constant = 400

Comment: Thanks @Prajakta for your response and sharing details.